# py2exe exe crashes when os module starts

Tags: python, py2exe

*py2exe* crashes when I start a part of my program, the open folder program that uses os.listdir(). Everything works in the python shell, but fails when used in *exe*.
I don't get any errors, in the *exe*, it just crashes. What do I need to add to my setup?

Here is my setup:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['drbOSbeta0.35(unfinished).py'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the file name:

```
setup(console=['drbOSbeta0.35(unfinished).py'])
```

to something like this

```
setup(console=['drbOSbeta0_35_unfinished.py'])
```

than try again.